# OMG, it's the HOLIDAY BOUNTY GIVEAWAY

Tags: discussion, winterbash, bounty

When I first saw the HatDash promotion, I thought to myself, that 'Won a Bounty' hat is going to be tough for people to get.  Yesterday, while I was contemplating how I could combine HATS and the HOLIDAY SPIRIT, the two things clicked in my brain, and this crazy idea was born.

### IT'S THE 2011 HOLIDAY BOUNTY GIVEAWAY.

Here are the rules:

- Keep your eyes peeled for underrated answers to questions - maybe it's one that came late to the party, or perhaps it's a game that's unpopular on the site so it's got low views, or whatever the reason.
- When you find an **underrated** answer, post a link *to the answer* along with a short description of who the person is you're nominating (so there's no ambiguity) and why you think the answer is *awesome*.  You may not nominate yourself, wise guys, especially those who act like wiseguys *[alot](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html)*.
- **RULES CHANGE** - after a few days of collecting nominations and votes, at his discretion badp will lock this question, preventing further answers and votes.  The **HOLIDAY BOUNTY DISTRIBUTION TEAM** will then go into high gear, awarding bounties as fast and as furious as we possibly can.  This might take multiple rounds, depending on the number of nominations and the number of team members.

  > **This question will be locked on Friday 23rd at [12:00 CET](http://time.is/12:00_in_CET).** (Well, roughly.) This should allow us to consign the biggest batches of reputation on the 25th itself.
- The bounty amount will depend on the number of votes the answer on this thread receives:

  - If the answer here has 0-5 net upvotes, I will award 50 points.
  - If the answer here has 6-10 net upvotes, I will award 100 points.
  - If the answer here has 11-15 net upvotes, I will award 150 points.
  - Finally, if the answer has 20 or more points, I will award **200 points.**  I don't think that person will get the Rep Cap hat for this, but we did what we could, and I would fully support a rules change if we could make that happen.

At least 20 bounties will be handed out, for a total of at least 4,000 rep.  That is, if you *pansies* can find that many underrated answers that can accumulate 20 upvotes.

And yeah, I went there.  I called you a pansy.  YOU THERE.  Total pansy.  Whatcha gonna do about it?  Find a bunch of excellent answers and then post them here and make them get enough votes in this thread so that I/we have to award a whole ton of 200 point bounties?  I DARE YOU.

Others have expressed interest in participating, and you will be able to join the **HOLIDAY BOUNTY DISTRIBUTION TEAM** by leaving a comment here.  If you let us know how much rep you're willing to contribute, we'll do our best to match you with some appropriate answers.

### YOUR HOLIDAY BOUNTY DISTRIBUTION TEAM:

Due to the way bounties work, if there are more bounties than the team can deliver in a single go, we'll have to do it in multiple waves.

- *badp* has pulled rank, and agreed to take the first three bounties (at whatever they're worth), and participate in future rounds as needed.
- *agent86* will take the second three bounties (at whatever they're worth), and participate in future rounds as needed.
- *bwarner* will take the next set of bounties, up to 200 rep.
- *McKay* will be awarding up to 200 rep.
- *Kevin Y* will be awarding up to 200 rep.
- *LessPopMoreFizz* will give some amount of rep, as long as it doesn't cost him his 20k privileges.

Comment: fyi bounty does not count towards rep cap so you are right, I don't think they'll get the hat

Comment: That said, just getting the attention from being here probably goes a long way to said rep cap hitting I'd wager.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Indeed.  The attention will be positive in addition to the potential for bounties.

Comment: I'm willing to part with a couple hundred rep as part of the distribution team.

Comment: I'll give some rep to the cause.

Comment: @McKay, how much shall I put you down for?

Comment: I'll part with whatever surplus above 20k rep I have when distribution time comes around. I suspect @badp would be upset with me if I put up more than that.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Your reputation is yours to spend, but I'd like to keep the 10kers and 20kers we do have :)

Comment: I'll give a 200. Or a 150, whatever you need.

Comment: I'll also give 200 rep towards these bounties.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Welp, first nominee:

[This incredible effort by Cor Blimey](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/42388/3129) to theorycraft out some Skyrim casting mechanics.

Comment: awarded by badp

Comment: Bounty claimed.

Comment: Bounty awarded.

Answer (score 10):

I would like to nominate [Mark Trapp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42284/how-can-i-build-a-simple-flip-flop-with-redstone) for his excellent answer to my relatively noobish question about Redstone.

The first pass at the question got closed due to the fact that the question was determined to be too broad, even though by that time he'd already answered it.  I edited it, and he went back and changed his already quite detailed answer to match the new version of the question, and then further answered my related questions in comments.  As of this writing, it only has 3 upvotes, and I think that's way less than it deserves.

Comment: This is assigned to **@bwarner** (100 pts)

Answer (score 10):

I further nominate [Dave DuPlantis](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42491/are-there-trains-in-saints-row-3), who when asked if there were trains in Saints Row 3, did a *complete circuit of the train tracks in the game* to prove his theory that there weren't any that ran the tracks.

He went further to note that there is something secret in one of the train cars, should you care to investigate.

Comment: awarded by agent86

Answer (score 10):

I'll nominate [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/42760/4775) by [Jeff Mercado](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/8995/jeff-mercado) for the effort put in to the drawings.

Honorable mention to [Anna Lear's](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/1925/anna-lear) answer on the [same question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/42757/4775) for the effort and pain of ascii drawings.  I'd upvote a separate nomination for this, but I feel weird nominating two answers on the same question.

Comment: They are both ridiculously awesome, and a fine example of why I love Gaming.SE - people do crazy awesome stuff like this in an effort to give answers. :)

Comment: awarded by badp

Comment: Bounty claimed for the Jeff Mercado answer

Comment: Bounty awarded.

Comment: And a big thanks from me!

Answer (score 10):

I'd like to nominate the [excellent answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/42956/3917) from [FallenAngelEyes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/160/fallenangeleyes) detailing how to get an achievement for the steam gift pile.

Comment: awarded by agent86

Answer (score 9):

Here's a pretty thorough [answer by BlueRaja](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/35502/10204) to a seemingly simple Easter Egg in Arkham City.

I say it is underrated simply because it's not the accepted one - his answer came after, but is very complete and even describes how to solve the more complex 3rd Easter Egg.

Comment: awarded by agent86

Comment: @agent86 Maybe I misunderstood how this works, but I think you awarded the bounty to the wrong answer.

Comment: argh, you're right, I did.

Answer (score 9):

I would also like to nominate this [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/40900/8350) by [John](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/5029/john). He took the time to do some testing, and also record a video of his efforts. I think that deserves more than 4 up votes, more so when you consider it has been viewed **453 times.**

Comment: This is assigned to **@McKay** (100 pts)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get notified? or I missed it. I should have paid better attention. I'm ready to do it now. It looks like it already has one? I'll give another of +100?

Comment: @McKay I believe that was not related to this contest, so award your 100 reputation.

Comment: That's what I presumed. I'm waiting 24 hours (http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3653/why-cant-i-award-a-bounty-immediately) :( Sorry about the delay.

Comment: Yeah, @McKay didn't get notified because he hadn't commented / edited this question.

Comment: Bounty awarded.

Answer (score 7):

I'll nominate [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/30851/8350) by [bgalin](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/12645/bgalin). He took the time to do some testing on his own in order to answers Oaks question. Any answer where the user takes the time to do such testing deserves more than 5 up votes.

Comment: This is assigned to **@LessPop_MoreFizz** (100 pts)

Comment: Bounty awarded.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to nominate [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/39098/118) to my question by [Jeff Mercado](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/8995/jeff-mercado). He did lots of testing on it, and then a month later(today), he did it all again when we realized there were two types.

Comment: This is assigned to **@Kevin Y** (100 pts)

Comment: Bounty awarded!