# Why can't I award a bounty immediately?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, bounty

So, I have the ability to award a bounty because I wish to award a particular answer. So, I do that on the question. This implies

1. I have already "lost" my reputation
2. I decided that one of the questions is worth giving my bounty to.

Why must I wait 24 hours?

Comment: possible duplic... oh wait. Related, anyway: [I want to award a bounty to an existing answer, should I have to wait 24 hours?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107282/i-want-to-award-a-bounty-to-an-existing-answer-should-i-have-to-wait-24-hours).

Comment: @lunboks Oh, it looks the same to me. Why do you think it's not quite a duplicate?

Comment: Because it's on MSO and closing as a cross-site duplicate isn't really possible.

Comment: @lunboks ah. that makes sense.

Comment: And I thought I checked for duplicates, and presumed I just wasn't very thorough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you give out a bounty immediately it seems potential abuse of the rep system where you could just rapidly dump rep to another user.  If this is related to [OMG, it's the HOLIDAY BOUNTY GIVEAWAY](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3506/omg-its-the-holiday-bounty-giveaway), I don't really care much for the whole pre-meditated bounty thing as people can just up-vote.

In any case, the "proper" use case of the bounty is to draw some additional eyes to a question, and as everyone is not always on (people sleep believe it or not), give other people a fair chance to craft a bounty-worthy answer.  There may be a good answer now, but there could also be a *great* answer if you wait some hours.

Comment: This is what I was figuring to post, though with the added note of "The majority use case of bounties involves getting new answers, so we're not concocting special case scenarios for picking a specific bounty reason".