# OMG HOLIDAY BOUNTY GIVEAWAY 2012

Tags: discussion, status-completed, bounty

> Nominations have ended!  Those of you who signed up for bounties and were matched have been pinged.  Go go go!

## OMG BOUNTY PROCESS 2012

Last year a bunch of us [gave away a bunch of rep](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3506/omg-its-the-holiday-bounty-giveaway) and that seemed to go over pretty well, so I thought perhaps we could do it again this year.  It's a fun way to use rep to benefit the community as a whole by rewarding exceptional questions and answers.

I'd like to expand it a bit and get a bit better organized, so here's what's going to happen:

1. Between now and **December 17th** - nominate questions (or answers) for bounties by posting a link and a short reason why as an answer to this question.
2. Vote up answers to this question that you think are deserving of a bounty.
3. On December 17th, we will lock this question.
4. If a nomination (consisting of an answer to this question) has a score between 0 and 4, it will earn 50 rep.  5-9 = 100 rep, 10-14 = 150 rep, and so forth.
5. The Bounty Distribution Team will award bounties by **leaving the question bountied for approximately a week starting on the 18th and awarding the bounty on the 24th.**

If the bounties to be awarded are more numerous than can be accommodated by the Bounty Distribution Team in one pass, we will continue this process of as many bounties we can issue, leaving each one on for a week if possible.

## OMG BOUNTIES

**You may nominate a question or answer for whatever reason** (since you're hoping for votes to get the bounty higher, you should be convincing!) - here are the "standard" bounty reasons for reference:

> - **Authoritative reference needed** - Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.
> - **Canonical answer required** - The question is widely applicable to a large audience. A detailed canonical answer is required to address all the concerns.
> - **Current answers are outdated** - The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.
> - **Draw attention** - This question has not received enough attention.
> - **Improve details** - The current answers do not contain enough detail.
> - **Reward existing answer** - One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.

Now's a perfect time to get an outdated answer updated, get an answer broadened to help answer the general case question better, acknowledge an underrated answer, or reward a particularly in-depth answer, among other reasons.

Do note that bounty system restrictions mean that **we can't give a second bounty on a question unless it is larger than the previous bounty.**  This means that if you nominate a question that has had a bounty already, you're going to have to convince a *lot* of people that it needs yet another one.

## OMG BOUNTY DISTRIBUTION TEAM

- agent86 - committing to award the three largest bounties, however high they may reach.
- badp has also expressed interest in joining, no details yet.
- bwarner becomes a repeat offender with 200 rep
- sarge_smith seasons our holiday cooking with 200 rep
- FAE is in danger of putting an eye out by throwing 500 rep at us
- Bora is feeling in a festive mood with 150 rep
- GnomeSlice is holding out on us, offering 50 rep
- AshleyNunn makes it rain (snow?) with 500 rep
- Ullallulloo does us good with 50 rep
- fredley is too cool for school and is *doing his own thing* like a rebel. And is also offering 200 rep. What a conformist
- Fluttershy is ponying up 200 rep
- LessPop_MoreFizz is keeping his cards close to his chest and knows when to fold.
- Jeffrey Lin wants to give a little bit, give a little bit of his rep to ussss with 150 rep.
- Fredy31 gives in 100 rep, and an angel gets it's wings!
- Ender shows up with a holiday donation of 500 rep
- Steve V. corrupts the holiday cheer with the mark of his beastly 200 rep

If you'd like to be on the Team, leave a comment with how much rep you're willing to donate, and I'll do my best to get everyone matched up with an appropriate bounty award (or awards, however that works out).  I will ping the team members in the comments and let you know how to apply your bounties when it's time to get to awarding.

Comment: I'm up for another 200.

Comment: I'll throw 200 in the pot as well

Comment: I'd contribute, but I'm almost at the 20k mark and I don't really want to extend the time it's going to take to get there.

Comment: Can we nominate ourselves? =P

Comment: I'll throw in 500.

Comment: My 150 rep say Merry Christmas..

Comment: @Fluttershy, you can, but then you've got to convince the community that you're not a dirty rep whore.  Some people might have an easier time at this than others :P

Comment: @agent86 D= A rep whore? I, sir, am just a pony.

Comment: @Fluttershy, I believe you!  It's *everyone else* you have to convince :P

Comment: If only [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/3#post-49061) was bounty-able

Comment: I feel like I should, but I gain rep so slowly now that I'm nearly making backwards progress with all of the bounties I keep giving out...

Comment: Put me down for 50 anyway.

Comment: I will throw in 500. :)

Comment: I'll do 50 rep.

Comment: I won't commit to a specific amount, but I'll go through some old Minecraft questions and bountify them if the answers have gone out of date and/or need sprucing up.

Comment: Ok, I actually read the post this time through. I'll *find* some posts and *nominate* them to be bountied, and you can have **200** of my ill-gotten rep.

Comment: I s'pose I can chip in 200 rep.

Comment: I may or may not be willing to throw around a 4 figure amount of 'exceptional answer' bounties, if there are nominees that I agree on the worthiness of. I'm kinda picky though. I definitely won't be throwing up any bounties on anything unanswered. I've largely given up on *that* aspect of the system. :(

Comment: I'll toss in **150** reputation as to give back to the community.

Comment: I'll give in 100 rep for this.

Comment: At this point we've got somewhere between 11 and 33 potential bounties, but only 7 nominations...  Let's get nominating, guys! :P

Comment: I will donate 500 reputation.

Comment: I'll kick in **200**, mostly because it'll give me a second chance to see my rep kick up to 6,666. (Obviously, the spirit of Christmas is in full effect)

Comment: @badp, can you get [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5583/13845) [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5592/13845) and [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5568/13845)?

Comment: @bwarner, can you bounty [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5586/13845) (for 100) and [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5595/13845) (also for 100)

Comment: @sarge_smith, bounties of 100 rep both on [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5590/13845) and [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5578/13845)

Comment: @FAE, you've got 3 50's on [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5591/13845), [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5575/13845) and [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5594/13845)

Comment: @Bora, you're the last of our bountiers with 50 on [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5607/13845)

Comment: There is still time for a small but from the bottom of my heart 100 Rep ?

Comment: @MichelAyres, nope, the nominations ended a couple of days ago, and we got a lot more offers of rep than we did bounties to award anyhow!

Comment: @agent86 thanks, I did one distribution by myself =)

Comment: I think @badp forgot about his.  I just bountied two of them, but I can't bounty my own.

Comment: Apologies for being a day late on awarding. I'm still stuck on dialup in an area with no mobile coverage, so I didn't have a chance to do this until now.

Answer (score 12):

I'll nominate [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/59211/1719) to a [league-of-legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/league-of-legends) question.

This was during the ggClassic contest, a dark time for all of us who remember it. This answer was a great turnaround to both the quality of answers we were getting on all questions in the tag, and also a turnaround in the quality of answers on that specific question, as evidenced by tzenes's comment on the question itself.

Answer (score 11):

I am going to nominate [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/47834/11502) by Wipqozn. I love it because it gives a very detailed answer to my question, complete with pictures and stars and a map and everything. This was something that had vexed me for a while, so getting an incredible answer like this was just total awesome.

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to nominate [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/95079/4775) by badp. When this question was [initially written](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/95074/revisions), it was incredibly localized and was quickly closed. Even after being reworded to be more generic, I figured the question was unanswerable without a list of current values for all items (which would in turn need constantly updated).

By providing many links to sources of sites that will handle these updates for us, badp turned a pretty bad question into a fantastic source of information for anyone looking to get into the TF2 trading scene.

Answer (score 8):

I'll nominate [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89190/how-do-i-repair-the-lighting-and-heater-in-the-cryo-chamber/89193#89193) by [GnomeSlice](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/3114/gnomeslice).

He gave a well-formatted answer with original pictures to something I couldn't figure out, and it's been a pretty unnoticed question/answer.

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to nominate [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/93888/14775) posted by [Sadly Not](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/1721/sadly-not) to a League of Legends question.

Let's face it, it's extremely rare that we get quality content posted in this tag. When we do manage to get a gem like this, it is often overlooked due to the small number of LoL players active on the site.

Answer (score 6):

I'm nominating [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/93983/14775) posted by [FAE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/160/fae) to a recent Guild Wars 2 question.

She's been a pretty valuable member of the community, providing a lot of quality content, and she puts a lot of time into answering questions for games about which she is passionate (I mean, look at her City of Heroes or Dear Esther answers!).

Answer (score 6):

I'll nominate [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66122/how-does-the-nephalem-valor-buff-work/66206#66206) from EBongo.  Its got a lot of well sourced information, the question has over 30k views, and it has been well maintained as changes have occurred from patch to patch.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to nominate [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79368/is-it-worth-it-to-let-trees-grow-taller/79370#79370) by Fluttershy.

It's a super detailed answer, with pictures and numbers and research, for (as far as I can tell from some brief internet research) a rather obscure game, and I think it is an awesome example of the quality content that he brings to Arqade :)

Answer (score 5):

I would like to nominate [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/93251/3921).

It is a thorough answer with a specifically-crafted walkthrough video. It is the symbol of dedicatement on this website.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to nominate [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63459/do-i-earn-less-experience-or-items-if-i-have-a-follower/63542#63542) by [Sean](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/21177/sean).

he did a well structured answer and with good references. He has being a great contributor for our community, not only with good questions/answer but also reviews and edits that improve our quality.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to nominate [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/70653/21619) by [skovacs1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/23580/skovacs1).

It involved excellent research, and superb original pictures.  The achievement the question was based on required many repetitive attempts on instanced areas, so this answer provides an excellent concise reference on where to look exactly.  I referred to it many times while working towards the achievement.

Answer (score 3):

I'll nominate [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/48548/) by [James](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/8581/james).

It gives a good, detailed overview of the perks with good formatting, and it was posted in just 14 seconds over an hour.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to nominate [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/57817/30570) by [Decency](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/11047/decency)

Although the question I feel is just looking for some differences between the two games, Decency had gone in depth to the metagame of the two games and although you might need to have experience in both the games to fully comprehend the subtle differences, it nevertheless provided me with a good read :D

Answer (score 1):

I would like to nominate [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/87518/3921).

It is a good answer to a fun question and the only question about a future indie GOTY called SpyParty.

Comment: Please don't nominate your own content, that's pretty bad form...

Comment: @Shinrai: You can't bounty a question anyway, and the answer's pretty good and not his.

Comment: @Ullallulloo - You're right, I really meant to post on his other self-nomination (where he also answered).  Point still stands, though - nominate the answers for their merits.